# jQuery: triggering (mousemove or "keypressed")

Tags: jquery, events, keypress, mousemove, onkeypress

I've read some answers regarding triggering mousemove any key pressed but I'm still not sure, what's the best way to unite both events - mousemove and pressing any key two in one.

What's the best way to modify

```
$(document).mousemove(function ()
{
  alert('The mouse was touched');
}
```

to

```
$(document).<???>(function ()
{
  alert('The mouse was touched or any key pressed');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `.on()`

```
$(document).on( "mousemove keypress", function () {
 code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having 3 functions is probably the best way to go.

```
$(document).mousemove(movePressed()); //calls function
$(document).keypress(movePressed()); //calls same function

function movePressed(){//do whatever you want when mousemove or keypressed}
```

Comment: There is no `keypressed` event and you are not registering the handlers, you are calling them, you should remove the `()`.

Comment: Yes, that is `keypress` not `keypressed`.

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry mate, my bad.